# Como resgatar a posição de um Sprite com Libgdx

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

Não estou conseguindo resgatar a posição de um sprite. quero resgatar a posição de apenas um sprite como faço?

```
public class Cubos extends Actor {
Sprite azul, verde, vermelho, amarelo, cinza;

public Cubos(){

    azul = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("texture.png")), 160, 0, 96,96);
    verde = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("texture.png")), 0, 192, 64,64);
    vermelho = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("texture.png")), 160, 96, 96,96);
    amarelo = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("texture.png")), 64, 0, 96,96);
    cinza = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("texture.png")), 256, 0, 96,96);

        }

public void act(float delta){
    super.act(delta);

    //Quero saber a posição X do azul ou amarelo eu faço "azul.getX() e retorna 0"
} }
```

Se eu escrevo por ex. `azul.getX()` retorna "0.0" mas se eu escrevo `this.getX()` retorna uma posição X não sei de qual cor.

Comment: `this.getX()` retorna a posição de *Actor*, `azul.getX()` retorna a posição do *sprite*. É da sua responsabilidade manter/alterar a posição do *sprite* em função da posição de *Actor*

Comment: Olá @ramaral, o problema e quando faço `azul.getX()` me retorna 0.0. Por quê será? Será que o correto seria usar uma cor para cada `extends Actor`?

Comment: Retorna `0` porque essa é a posição por defeito ao  criar uma instância de *sprite*. Em relação à segunda pergunta isso depende, como não sei qual é o seu propósito não posso responder. Você deveria ver/ler um tutorial sobre [Scene2d](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPIeERAm2ao) antes de começar a tentar escrever código.